# android if dialog is shown

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, final

I have shaker and on shake motion i want to show dialog. And i have issue when there is multiple shakes performed, so multiple dialogs is shown. I want show only one dialog at time.

So i wrote this code but it shows errors. One line wants "final AlertDialog" and another line wants it without "final"

```
      public void onShake() {

        final AlertDialog builder = null;
         if(!builder.isShowing()){

            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent()).create(); -- error if final is casted on AlertDialog -- "The final local variable builder cannot be assigned. It must be blank and not using a compound assignment"

            builder.setTitle("Shake");


            builder.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                    builder.dismiss(); -- requires final AlertDialog -- "Cannot refer to a non-final variable builder inside an inner class defined in a different method"

                }
            });
            builder.show();

      }}
```

**EDIT:** Thanks, dialog.builder(); looks working. But now i have faced new problem - NullPointerException, throwed on line where i check if alert dialog is shown or not.
Now im trying:

```
if(builder.isShowing() == false)
```

**Fixed NullPointerException**

```
if(builder == null){
builder.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    builder = null; 
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `builder.dismiss()` to `dialog.dismiss()`

Comment: Try to create your dialog just once, so you cam check if it's been created and, if yes, if it's showing

Comment: I think that wont work for me, because i want make another dialog available if user dismiss first dialog and do shake again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `builder.dismiss();` and replace it with `dialog.dismis()`, on the listener you get a dialog object which corresponds to the dialog on which the event was triggered

Answer (score 0):

Declare the AlertDialog as a field in your activity and dont need to set it as final.